# Как импортировать библиотеку IEngineLibrary?

Tags: java, библиотеки, jar, импорт, classpath

Я добавил `jar`-файл в проект, в `classpath` автоматически добавилась вот эта строчка:

```
<classpathentry kind="con"
path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/IEngineLibrary"/>".
```

Как мне теперь его использовать? в `IEngineLibrary` находится `lwjgl.jar`.

`import IEngineLibrary.` - ничего не видит.
`import lwjgl.` - ничего не видит.

На некоторых сайтах пишут:

> import org.lwjgl.someclass

Но и это не помогает.

Я добавил `jar`-файл и как `referenced library`, и как просто библиотеку (`user library`), и как `jar-file` (вне библиотеки), но `import` ничего не видит.

Answer (score 0):

короче, оказывается в import указывается сразу пакет, который находится в библиотеке. а ещё он не может читать jar файлы, если они сами состоят из многих jar файлов внутри.